# How can pass on a number id instead of a string id?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

My api consumes a number instead of a string id. If I want to do so, I get the error:Type string cannot be assigned to type number. Does the `param` function only take strings as id or how can I change that to a number?

Here is my code:

user.service.ts

```
// get a user's profile
  getUserDetails(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users/${id}/`); 
  }
```

user.page.html

```
 <ion-avatar  class="user-image"  slot="start" [routerLink]="['/', 'friendsdet', 'id']">
        <ion-img src="assets/9.jpeg"> </ion-img>
 </ion-avatar>
```

friendsdet.page.ts

```
information: null;
id: number;
...
  ngOnInit() {
     // Get the ID that was passed with the URL
     this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => { 
      this.id = params.get('id'); 
  });


     // Get the information from the API
     this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id).subscribe(result => {
       this.information = result;
       console.log(result);
     });
   }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
...

     { path: 'friendsdet/:id', 
      loadChildren: './external-user/friendsdet/friendsdet.module#FriendsdetPageModule'
      },
    ...
```

Comment: Everything in an URL is a string. How should JavaScript/Angular know that the key value pair id=... will have a number as value? Hence [`param.get()`](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap#get) will always return a string. Just convert it to a number.

Comment: could you show the full code for `user.page.html`. with this code: `[routerLink]="['/', 'friendsdet', 'id']"` you are passing the literal string `'id'`.

Comment: As @Andreas already told you, you're looking for a way to convert a `string` into a `number`. Add a __+__ `this.id = +param.get('id');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values from an url will always be strings. It's your code's job to validate and convert them to what they need to be. In your case, you can use the `parseInt()` function to take a string and change it to a number.

You should also validate that the input is really a number, maybe using a regex or the `Number.isInteger` function.

```
  ngOnInit() {
     // Get the ID that was passed with the URL
     this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => { 
      this.id = validateId(params.get('id')); 
  });

function validateId(id: any) : number {
    if(!Number.isNumeric(id)){
       console.error('number is not a number');
    }
    return parseInt(id);
}
```

Comment: Thx I think that will work. But atm I always get that id is NaN. Has this something to do with that part
    `<ion-item *ngFor="let friend of (friendsList | async); let i = index">    
       <ion-avatar  class="user-image"  slot="start" [routerLink]="['/', 'friendsdet', 'friend.id']">
        <ion-img src="assets/9.jpeg"> </ion-img>
 </ion-avatar>
</ion-item>` that I need to get like the correct property for id? Because I know api is giving a number

Comment: @ColinRagnarök it looks like you are passing `'friend.id'` as the id, it is not supose to be a string at this point. Just pass `friend.id` no quotes.

Comment: great that fixed it!:) Thank you.  The console still logs that if isInteger still actually says its not a Number. But somehow the api request is made and I get back the data

Answer (score -3):

Let's try **id: any;** instead of **id: number;**